# How to calculate bond length using ase?

Tags: ase

I know a function ase.Atoms.get_distance but I don't know how to use it.

Is there other functions I can use and how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of the `atom` object in your `atoms` object
you could probably do something like atoms[1].get_position and atoms[2].get_position and subtract the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If `mol` is an `ase.Atoms` object, use:

`mol.get_distance(atom_index1, atom_index2)`